# "Class datatables does not exist" Error when using "yajra" laravel datatables

Tags: datatable, laravel-5

I want to show a list of my posts table rows via **[datatables](https://www.datatables.net)** jquery plugin with laravel version 5.1 via [**yajra-laravel-datatables**](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

For that I do all instructions described in this [Quick Start Giude](http://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter) in my project.

this is my Route only for get all data that are Necessary for dataTable:

```
Route::get('postsData', 'postController@testData');
```

and this is complete postController php file :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

class postController extends Controller
{

    public function index ()
    {
        $allPosts = Post::all();
        return \View::make('admin.pages.posts')->with('posts', $allPosts);
    }


    public function create ()
    {
        return \View::make('admin.pages.post_create');
    }


    public function store (Request $request)
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        $rules = array (
            'post_title' => 'required',
            'post_desc'  => 'required'
        );

        $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return \Redirect::to('/admin/posts/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {

            $post             = new Post();
            $post->post_title = $data['post_title'];
            $post->post_desc  = $data['post_desc'];
            $post->save();

            return \Redirect::to('/admin/posts');
        }
    }


    public function show ($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        return \View::make('admin.pages.show_post')->with('post', $post);
    }


    public function edit ($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return \View::make('admin.pages.edit_post')->with('post', $post);
    }


    public function update (Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        $rules = array (
            'post_title' => 'required',
            'post_desc'  => 'required'
        );

        $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return \Redirect::to('post/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {

            $post             = Post::find($id);
            $post->post_title = $data['post_title'];
            $post->post_desc  = $data['post_desc'];
            $post->save();

            return \Redirect::to('admin/posts');
        }
    }


    public function destroy ($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();

        return Redirect::to('admin/posts');
    }


    public function postsAll(){
        return View::make('admin.pages.postsAll');
    }

    public function testData(){
        return Datatables::of(Post::select('*'))->make(true);
    }
}
```

also I add **Service Provider and Facade** to **config/app.php** :

```
return [
    'debug'           => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
    'url'             => 'http://localhost',
    'timezone'        => 'UTC',
    'locale'          => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'key'             => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
    'cipher'          => 'AES-256-CBC',
    'log'             => 'single',


    'providers'       => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
        yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],



    'aliases'         => [

        'App'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Bus'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'         => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'   => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Input'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
        'Inspiring'  => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
        'Lang'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Datatables' => yajra\Datatables\Datatables::class,

    ],

];
```

And this is Structure of **yajra** in **vendor** composer folder:

[image]

But when I open **postsData** path in browser this error shown:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
Class datatables does not exist
```

What is Problem?

Comment: I had some problem. I have tried the below solution. No solution work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution after hours of googling and try different ways :

1.first rename your project to a new name.
2.use `composer update`
3.run `php artisan config:cache`
4.and run `php artisan cache:clear`

and try your Code again.

Comment: Why the new name ?

Comment: this post is for 5 months ago, I didn't remember why exactly. maybe for Ensure and Avoid caching.

Answer (score 3):

Try change in your controller

Remove:

```
use yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
```

Add

```
use Datatables;

config/app.php
```

You must have in providers:

```
 yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
```

and must have in aliases:

```
'Datatables' => yajra\Datatables\Datatables::class,
```

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I manage to fix the same bugs.

In config/app.php

```
Yajra\DataTables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
Datatables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\Datatables::class,
```

Just make sure you capitalize 'T' in the '\DataTables\'

Ref. https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/986

Answer (score 1):

same error has also happened if you don't have conf/datatables.php. try installing latest or above 7.x

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
```

add these lines in config/app.php

```
Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,

'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class,

php artisan config:cache
```

if you don't have file config/datables.conf. Try to paste these file there.
https://gist.github.com/hsali/1cab0d6c81020bf7bce043b65f94373a

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;
```